# Family Tree of Asuras

Tags: scripture, asuras, genealogy

The most comprehensive one I know of is my own chart of the genealogy of sapient/civilization building races and their deity Upendra form I made through trial and error till I got something that made sense (especially internally). Does anyone know any better version or one more focused on the Asura?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Asura is a broad term.. u may restrict it to Daityas or Danvas or Rakshasas etc.?

Comment: @YDS Everything is related though, so the more through the chart the better.

Comment: Q should not be too broad actually, it has to be focused..